# Access Form.Requery Working Inconsistently

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am having an issue with an Access Form Requery method working inconsistently.

I have two forms. The first form is a `Data_Entry` form for the user. The second form is a `Dashboard` display that arranges and formats important data from the first form. On the `Data_Entry` form, there is a button the user can press to force a Requery event on both the `Data_Entry` and `Dashboard` forms. It is very simple code:

```
Private Sub Button_Update_Click()
    Form_Data_Entry.Requery
    Form_Dashboard.Requery
End Sub
```

Within the `Dashboard` form, I also have a timer event that triggers every 60 seconds:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

About 50% of the time these all work as expected. About 45% of the time, the update button on the `Data_Entry` form will Requery itself, but will do nothing to the dashboard; however, clicking on the `Dashboard` and pressing F5 will force the Requery, as will the timer event. The other 5% of the time, neither the update button nor F5 nor the timer will Requery the `Dashboard`.

100% of the time, the update button will requery the `Data_Entry` form without issue.

If I close the `Dashboard` and reopen it, it will work again as expected… for awhile. Sometimes it will go for hours without issue, other times only 15 minutes.

I am at a loss as to what is causing this inconsistent behavior. It doesn’t appear to be a VBA issue. Is this some kind of deeper problem within the Access source code itself, or am I missing something obscure elsewhere?

Comment: Is the recordsource of the forms based on a query (Maybe you requery always a different recordsource based on code)? Do your forms remember the filter (this way it requerys with the filter on)? Do you work in W-LAN (If you lose the connection to the backend the requerys dosnt work anymore)?

Comment: @Strawberryshrub the record source is based on a query, which itself is based on another query. I do not have a filter on the form itself. The product front/back are all self contained. There is no external connection.

Comment: I still have no idea what caused this bizarre bug, but I came up with a solution for it (below). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, but I still do not know what is causing it. I found that either opening the form from VBA code or from Access Macro would still present the same problem, but closing the form once and reopening it would make the problem go away for the duration of the session. Therefore, I modified the code for the button to open the display form to first open the form, close it, and then reopen it. Problem solved.

```
Private Sub Button_DisplayName_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm “FORM_NAME”
    DoCmd.Close acForm, “FORM_NAME”, acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm “FORM_NAME”
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with this bug. Re-assigning the records is what finally worked for me, weird but it seems to consistently clear this glitch in my case.

```
rs = Me.Form.RecordSource
Me.Form.RecordSource = rs
Me.Requery
```